# How to get count for a particular key in the dictionary with values as list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My content inside a dictionary is below

I need to know count for 1. BusinessArea and its count of values

2. Designation and its count of values

```
 test= [ { 'masterid': '1', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ 'Accounting','Research'], 'Designation': [ 'L1' 'L2' ] }, { 'masterid': '2', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': ['Research','Accounting' ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Tester' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer' } ], 'Designation': [ 'L1' 'L2' ]}, { 'masterid': '3', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ 'Engineering' ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Developer' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer', 'parentname': '' } ], 'Designation': [ 'L1'  ]}]
```

I want to get the count of masterid of BusinessArea and Designation which is all the names

Expected out is below

```
[
  {
    "name": "BusinessArea",
    "values": [
      {
        "name": "Accounting",
        "count": "2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Research",
        "count": "2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Engineering",
        "count": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Designation",
    "values": [
      {
        "name": "L1",
        "count": "3"
      },
      {
        "name": "l2",
        "count": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

masterid 1,2 and 3 there are L1 and masterid 1 and 2 there are L2 so for L1:3, and L2:2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like the below (not exactly the output you mentioned but quite close..)

```
from collections import defaultdict

test = [{'masterid': '1', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': ['Accounting', 'Research'], 'Designation': ['L1', 'L2']},
        {'masterid': '2', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': ['Research', 'Accounting'],
         'Role': [{'id': '5032', 'name': 'Tester'}, {'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer'}], 'Designation': ['L1', 'L2']},
        {'masterid': '3', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': ['Engineering'],
         'Role': [{'id': '5032', 'name': 'Developer'}, {'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer', 'parentname': ''}],
         'Designation': ['L1']}]

b_area = defaultdict(int)
des = defaultdict(int)
for entry in test:
    for val in entry['BusinessArea']:
        b_area[val] += 1
    for val in entry['Designation']:
        des[val] += 1
print(b_area)
print(des)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Accounting': 2, 'Research': 2, 'Engineering': 1})
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'L1': 3, 'L2': 2})
```